# Prove $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}{(-1)^i \binom{2n}{i}^3} = (-1)^n \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}$

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I've tried to look at it combinatorically but I couldn't find a good model for $\binom{2n}{k}^3$, I've also tried to solve it using induction but the changes in steps are too much to keep track of

Can any one give a hint on any kind of proof for this?

Comment: How about start by expanding the meaning of the binomial coefficient?

Comment: Also you can take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793256/non-inductive-not-combinatorial-proof-of-sum-i-mathop-0n-binom-n-i2?rq=1

Comment: Should $k$ be $i$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier yes. Thanks I fixed it

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084326/how-to-prove-sum-k-1nk-binomnk-n2n-1?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683733/sum-of-k-n-choose-k-is-n2n-1

Comment: Up to sign, the RHS is $3n\choose n$$2n\choose n$

Comment: Also related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652748/prove-binom3nn-n-n-frac3nnnn-is-always-divisible-by-6-when

Comment: COMMENT.- In order to apply induction it could be useful to consider
$$\binom{2(n+1)}{i}=\binom{2n}{i-2}+2\binom{2n}{i-1}+\binom{2n}{i}$$ and
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n}{(-1)^i \binom{2n}{i}}=2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{(-1)^i \binom{2n}{i}}+\binom{2n}{n}$$ (no time now to try to solve the problem).

Comment: This is called **Dixon's identity**. An illuminating, yet non-elementary way is to recognize the LHS as a $_3F_2$ (generalized) hypergeometric function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity. Alternatively, this seems provable using WZ-pairs.